# Assembly AMD64 gradient error

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, gradient, x86-64

I'm not sure where I have errored, I'm trying to output a gradient pattern from 0-255 red horizontally and 0-255 green vertically. I know the linked files worked correctly as they have been throughly tested. Any help would be very appreciated.

```
global _start
global start
extern writeRGB
extern writeHeader

_start:
        call start

sys_write:  equ 1
sys_open:   equ 2
sys_close:  equ 3
sys_exit:   equ 60

newLine : equ 10

section .data
filename:       db "gradient.ppm", 0

section .bss

buffer: resb 4096

section .text

start:

        push r12
        push r13
        push r14
        push r15
        push rbx
        push rbp

        mov rax, sys_open       ; setup to open file
        mov rdi, filename       ; move filename
        mov rsi, 577            ; given
        mov rdx, 0o644          ; given
        syscall                 ; open file

        cmp rax, 0              ; check status
        jl end

        mov r12, 0              ; red
        mov r13, 0              ; green  
        mov r14, rax            ; opened file
        mov r15, buffer         ; buffer
        mov rbx, 0              ; buffer counter

        lea rdi, [r15+rbx]      ; setup for writeheader call
        mov rsi, 256
        mov rdx, 256
        call writeHeader
        add rbx, rax            ; add buffer space used by writeheader
        call makeRGB            ; create 0 0 0 rgb
        lea rdi, [r15+rbx]      ; setup for writeRGB
        call writeRGB
        add rbx, rax            ; add buffer space used by writeRGB
        call incRed 

incRed:
        call addSpace
        inc r12                 ; red++
        call makeRGB            ; convert to RBG
        lea rdi, [r15+rbx]      ; setup for writeRGB call
        call writeRGB           
        add rbx, rax            ; add buffer space used by writeRGB
        cmp r12, 255            ; check to see if end of row
        jl incRed               ; if not end of row repeat
        je incGreen             ; if end of row start new row

incGreen:
        cmp r13, 255            ; if last line is written move to end
        je write
        call addNewLine
        mov r12, 0              ; reset red to 0
        inc r13                 ; green++
        call makeRGB            ; convert to RGB
        lea rdi, [r15+rbx]      ; setup for writeRGB call
        call writeRGB
        add rbx, rax            ; add buffer space used by writeRGB
        call addSpace
        jmp incRed              ; ret to incRed

makeRGB:
        mov r12, rsi            ; mov red into rsi
        shl rsi, 8              ; shift left 8 to make room for green
        add rsi, r13            ; add green
        shl rsi, 8              ; shift left to set blue to 0
        ret

addSpace:
        mov al, ' '             ; insert space
        mov [r15+rbx], al
        inc rbx
        ret

addNewLine:
        mov al, newLine         ; insert newline
        mov [r15+rbx], al
        inc rbx 
        ret

write:
        mov rax, sys_write
        mov rdi, r14            ; move opened file into rdi
        mov rsi, r15            ; buffer location
        mov rdx, rbx            ; load buffer size
        syscall                 ; write to file
        mov rbp, rax            ; status stored in rbp
        cmp rbp, 0              ; check status
        jl end

        mov rdi, r14            ; move opened file into rdi
        mov rax, sys_close      ; close file
        syscall

        call end                ; end

end:
        pop rbp
        pop rbx
        pop r15
        pop r14
        pop r13
        pop r12

        mov rdi, rax            ; prepare to exit
        mov rax, sys_exit       
        syscall                 ; exit
```

Comment: You forgot to mention what the error is ... also, even though you claim the other parts are tested, it wouldn't be the first time something like that was broken. In any case, we can't test it if you don't provide a [MCVE]. In the meantime, learn to use a debugger so you can find the error yourself.

Comment: What is your `nasm` invocation? I downloaded your file and a simple `nasm` flagged lines with `[r15+rbx]` as "impossible combination of address sizes" or "invalid effective address"

Comment: @CraigEstey that's an entirely valid address, sounds like you have a problem not OP :) You might not be assembling as 64 bit.

Comment: @Jester I never said it was invalid. I was just reporting what I did, which was `nasm foo.s`. That's why I asked if there were any special options needed (e.g. `--format=<whatever>`). In lieu of that, the simplest invocation should work. Actually, `nasm -f elf64 foo.s` works

Comment: Yeah, OP should have shown the command line, but it's obviously 64 bit code, and he had no problems with that part.

Comment: Sorry, its returns 'segmentation error'.  I can post a copy later this evening of what the command line returns. This is a school assignment and the other pieces were provided by the prof.

Comment: I assumed the linked/external .o's were like that. Makes it difficult for anyone else to actually link and run the program. Otherwise, `gdb` _can_ debug asm [albeit with a bit of work]. (e.g.) stepping one asm inst at a time is `stepi`. If you could post the actual line that fails that might help. Also, if you can't post the external [source] code, the function prototypes [with doc on args and ret values] might help.